# Why does file stay in index after commit?

Tags: git

I have been reading [What's the deal with the git index](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/whats-the-deal-with-the-git-index/#session) but can someone explain me why a file stays in the index after it has been committed. I don't see why this is necessary...

Comment: You must be missing something, the index is reset after a commit

Comment: It is. The index is what will become a commit, when the commit is created the index is flushed, as BenJames says.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you when you said 'reset'. You are right, indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it helps to note that Git stores your repository history in terms of snapshots, not patches.

So, when you run `git status` and see that you have no staged changes, this does not mean the index is "empty".

It means there is *no difference* between the snapshot that is in the index, and the latest commit (more accurately, the commit referenced by `HEAD`).

Comment: Your first sentence already clarifies a lot but then it is still not clear to me what the index actually IS.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of it is that the index always holds what would be the contents of the next commit if you did a `git commit`. So, immediately after a commit, it should contain exactly the contents of that commit. As you make further modifications, you add those to the index to craft your next commit.